# ModelClass.class.getDeclaredFields().length returns 4 during Gradle Build but there are 3 declared attributes

Tags: java, gradle, reflection, build.gradle, junit4

I have the following POJO class:

```
public class ModelClass {

    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String marks;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(String marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

I have a test method where the requirement is to get total number of attributes declared in the model class at runtime and verify it. Following is the code snippet in my test class:

```
@Test
public void demoTest() {
    int fields = ModelClass.class.getDeclaredFields().length;
    assertEquals(CUSTOM_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, fields, 3);
}
```

This test is running fine in Eclipse when I run it as Junit test. But during the build it fails saying:

> java.lang.AssertionError:expected:<4> but was:<3>
>       at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
>       at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
>       at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)

Apparently, during Gradle build, the value of fields is coming out to be 4, but should have been 3.

This is a Gradle Project. Can anyone shed some light on this unusual behaviour?

Comment: at first, print  obtained values - it's can help you for understanding. at second, I'm not sure, but maybe the fourth is constructor?

Comment: @ZhenyaM Its printing out the three attributes correctly, I did not see any random fourth attribute in the console. I did not get your second part where you mentioned the constructor.

Comment: I mean in test make print: `ModelClass.class.getDeclaredFields().forEach(field -> System.out.println(field.getName());` or just debug this test

Comment: And this is the output:                                                                                              
                                                                                                          
_italic_private java.lang.String com.cerner.soarian.sf.regulatoryinterfaces.professional.ModelClass.name
private java.lang.String com.cerner.soarian.sf.regulatoryinterfaces.professional.ModelClass.phone
private java.lang.String com.cerner.soarian.sf.regulatoryinterfaces.professional.ModelClass.marks_italic_

Comment: Also I would like to point out that the test is failing once the build is triggered, but when I am running the test as junit from eclipse its passing.

Comment: so what's the output of declared fields when it is failing? you need to add the information to the question.

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help troubleshoot this. What version of Gradle are you using? What command are you running on the command line? What does your build script look like?

Comment: @user3798849, at first, please, add fields name output to the question. at second, try to rename `marks` field and restart tests for gradle build. you'r output very strange for this field and I think it could be source of problem for gradle

Answer (score -1):

`getDeclaredFields()` method returns an array of field objects . So, `getDeclaredFields().length` should return the `length of the array`. Whether your `assertEquals` condition comprises with comparison of 3 units and the method holds length of 0(default) to 3(three methods declared in your `ModelClass`) = 4 (**n.b. This method returns an array of length 0 if the class or interface declares no fields, or if this Class object represents a primitive type, an array class, or void**, basically it returns the value for constructor) .

Here I have tested your code and sharing the return which might help you have a better comprehension:

[Served from mid night eclipse :-)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6TLE.jpg)